# Make Database query only when option is updated

Tags: plugin-development, php, database, options

Below is a DB query I am using to retrieve values and place them in a WP_List_Table.  Values are currently being added by `add_option`, then those values are converted into a custom database table called `wp_testimonials`.  I have no clue why I did it this way, but it works!

So now I need to create a conditional that says "if user is currently updating the option, then update the table after the option is updated, else don't do anything."

However, I do not know how to state this condition.  My display table is located in a different file than where the options are being updated.

Below is the database query, which is currently updating every time I access the page and needs to be changed.

```
      $options = get_option('testimonials_settings');  
          if ( isset ($options)) {  
          global $wpdb;
          $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "testimonials";
          $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
          id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          name tinytext NOT NULL,
          company_name text NOT NULL,
          company_url text NOT NULL,
          testimonials_quote text NOT NULL,
          UNIQUE KEY id (id)
      );";
          require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
          dbDelta($sql);

         $name = $options['testimonials_name'];
         $company_name = $options['testimonials_website_name'];
         $company_url = $options['testimonials_website_url'];
         $testimonials_quote = $options['testimonials_quote'];
         $rows_affected = $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 'name' => $name, 'company_name' => $company_name, 'company_url' => $company_url, 'testimonials_quote' => $testimonials_quote ) );

      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `update_option` includes action hooks that you can use.

Use `update_option_{$option_key}` as shown here:

```
function my_func($option, $value) {
  //this is called only when that particular option is updated
  //$option has the option key & $value has the value array
}
add_action('update_option_testimonials_settings', 'my_func', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Hi Mridul, I'm just a little confused here - do I need to substitute any of the values in your answer, I'm thinking "no" but I could be wrong.

Comment: No the code example is complete by itself. I replaced `{$option_key}` with the actual name of the key there

Comment: OK, last time I tried that and it didn't work. I tested to see if I'm retrieving value correctly, and it seems that I am. Should I simply wrap your function around my existing code, as it was posted in the question?

Comment: Nevermind, Mridul.....I changed `add_option_{$option_key}` to `update_option_{$option_key}` and it worked!  Thanks so much...

Comment: It should have worked with `add_option` too. but anyways i'm glad you got it working.